# Get the name of a rails gem inside a rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rake

I would like to build a rake task and distribute it as a gem. It is included in target gems. When invoked inside a target it should generate a file with the name of the target gem. But I can't find a way to get the name of the target gem inside which a the rake tasks is invoked.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: What do you mean by "target gem"? If something imports your gem you never really find out why. Your code just gets loaded.

Comment: Target gem is the gem in which I run the task provided the gem I am developing. If my gem is called "gem_with_a_rake_task" the target gem is the one that does "gem 'gem_with_a_rake_task'". Inside of the target gem I am doing rake my_task where my_task is provided by "gem_with_a_rake_task". Inside my task I need to find the name of the target gem. The name of the gem where 'rake my_task" is called.

Answer (score 2):

It's not entirely clear to me what you mean by target gems, but it's possible to get the current gem's name within a rake task.

In your rakefile:

```
desc 'Gets the gem name'
task 'gemname' do 
  gemspec = Bundler.load_gemspec(Dir.glob('*.gemspec').first)
  puts gemspec.name
end
```

Comment: How do I find the value of "your_gem" in this task? If I already know it I don't need gemspec.name

Comment: Assuming there is one gemspec file, which should be the case, you can use a glob - `gemspec = Bundler.load_gemspec(Dir.glob(File.join(__dir__, '*.gemspec')).first)`

Comment: After reading your target gem description - if you add the task to gem_with_a_rake_task, but require the file containing the task in the Rakefile of the target gem, you can try to use `gemspec = Bundler.load_gemspec(Dir.glob('*.gemspec').first)`. The path the gob will search is wherever you ran rake from, assuming you dont change cwd in the code.

Comment: No, but could you update the answer? Because the answer contains your_gem.gemspec